# Image_Picker_Widget en app web no asigna el file

Tags: flutter

**Este Es Mi Codigo**

```
 ImagePickerWidget(
                            diameter: 180,
                            initialImage:
                            "assets/mundogris.png",
                            shape: ImagePickerWidgetShape.circle,
                            isEditable: true,
                            shouldCrop: true,
                            onChange: (File file) {
                             _image = file;
                            },
                          ),
```

> The following UnsupportedError was thrown resolving an image codec: Unsupported operation: _Namespace

*Estoy tratando de asignar una imagen de mi galeria a la variable _image como File para mas tarde poderla subir al cloud de Firebase

Graias*

Comment: A ver, ¿Qué es ImagePickerWidget? ¿De dónde sale? ¿Lo has creado tú? ¿Es de un paquete/plugin? De ser así, ¿cuál es? Creo que haría falta que añadieras un poco más de código, porque solo con eso, al menos yo no soy capaz de ver de dónde viene el problema. No tienes que poner el código de toda la pantalla, pero hombre, viene bien el código que esté estrechamente relacionado con tu problema y con lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Está usando paquete image_picker_widget? Este es solo for ios y android. No puede usar en web app.

Comment: **Manuel**: el paquete de Image_picker_widget esta en pub.dev y ese es el codigo, solo necesito asignar a esa variable la imagen seleccionada con el paquete, pero por lo que dice **Scott** el paquete no es para web es solo para mobile, gracias por la respuesta, realmente aprendo muchisimo de cada participacion aqui.
**Scott:** Gracias por el tip creo que mi priblema puede ser ese voy a buscar algun paquete de image picking que sea para web.